# How to convert a makeflie.mak from Visual Studio 11 into Visual Studio 17?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, makefile, visual-studio-2017, compatibility

Today I ask myself if it's possible to convert/upgrade an Visual Studio 2011/12 makefile.mak into a Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise file/version?
Maybe it's neccessary to create it from scratch or an empty template but I am not sure.

Here is what I got already:

```
 # Microsoft specific Programms/Configs     
 CC      = cl
 LINK    = link
 LIB     = lib
 INCLPATH= "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE"
 COMPOPT = -I$(INCLPATH) -c
 LINKOPT = /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\DIA SDK\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual     Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\lib" //Path?
 LIBOUT  = /OUT:

 #Targets
 all: exercise9_4.exe clean

 exercise9_4.exe: exercise9_4.obj customer.lib
     $(LINK) $(LINKOPT) uebung9_4.obj customer.lib

 exercise9_4.obj: exercise9_4.c 
     $(CC) $(COMPOPT) exercise9_4.c

 customer.lib: customer.obj
     $(LIB) $(LINKOPT) customer.obj

 customer.obj: customer.c customer.h
     $(CC) $(COMPOPT) customer.c customer.h

 clean: 
     del exercise9_4.obj
     del customer.lib
     del customer.obj
```

Question which paths do I need in VisualStudio 2017?
Did the commands change? 
I would really appriciate your help. :D
Because VS2017 reclaims an Upgrade is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy Solution:
Remove Paths, Blank Spaces, insert correct paths(link, cl, lib)
Open it in Visual Studio 2015 Dev-Console,
put in "nmake makefile.mak" -> hit enter, wait a few seconds,
it works :D